# DBeaver and Nettezza

Tags: netezza, dbeaver

I am trying to use DBeaver for Netezza. My driver is the same as the one I am using for DBvisualizer.
When I run a query, I get `NullPointerException` for all Timestamp and Date columns. The same query runs in DBvisualizer perfectly.
Does anyone know why?
(my machine is a Mac OS)